# Unable to connect remotely to Vsftpd server set up on CentOS VirtualBox

Tags: centos, ftp, virtualbox, vsftpd

I have set up a Vsftp server using the following instructions provided [Here](http://ostechnix.wordpress.com/2013/12/15/setup-ftp-server-step-by-step-in-centos-6-x-rhel-6-x-scientific-linux-6-x/) and even went as far as following the commentary at the bottom. But I am unable to connect remotely. When I attempt to use FileZilla or my Ubuntu terminal, I always get:

```
ryan@ryan-Galago-UltraPro:~$ ftp 10.0.x.xx
ftp: connect: Connection timed out
ftp>
```

I have checked and re-checked `iptables` conf file and made sure that Port 21 is being Accepted and it is. I have looked this up on the web and decided to try `nmap` to port scan it and this is what I get for a result:

```
ryan@ryan-Galago-UltraPro:~$ nmap -PN 10.0.xx.xx

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-08-19 15:01 EDT
Nmap scan report for 10.0.xx.xx
Host is up.
All 1000 scanned ports on 10.0.xx.xx are filtered

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 201.38 seconds
```

Is there anything else that I should do or check for?

UPDATE: I have tried to ping from the virtual machine to my IP address on Ubuntu and have been successfully able to. I cannot ping to my virtual machine from Ubuntu. I have narrowed this down to possibly being a firewall related issue on Ubuntu's side, but why would I be unable to connect from FileZilla?

Comment: Can you ping from the host to the guest? Could you run `ifconfig` in the guest and add its output to your question? What is the guest's network interface attached to? It's set to NAT, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot assure your error is because of SE Linux context issue, but try changing context using following command

```
chcon -Rt public_content_t /var/ftp/pub
```

To Display the context

```
ls -Z /var/ftp/pub
```

Additionally set Boolean value as follows

```
setsebool -p ftp_home_dir 1

setsebool -p allow_ftpd_full_access 1
```

After all restart the service

```
service vsftpd restart
```

Comment: The only folder i see in `/var/ftp/` is pub, so I followed as instructed and still can't connect from outside source. Is there a way to disable SE Linux?

Comment: try the command setenforce 0 then check getenforce and confirm it is in permissive mode, then check it again.FYI this will only disable selinux temporarily..

Comment: I turned selinux to permissive. And still nothing, this is so frusterating how they make these how-to articles so easy and yet it isnt

Comment: check ping to your ip, also check tcpwrapper, firewall and kerberos,answer edited check again

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: ru trying to connect from unbuntu ? if you set firewall and block all outgoing connections for port number 20 and 21 how can you connect to ftp ? try the command ftp <ip address>

Comment: I am trying to connect from ubuntu and disabled firewalls on CentOS and Ubuntu and I still cannot connect. I have already tried that command many times